# How to load a reportviewer via datatable/dataset

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, reportviewer

Have the following to load a reportviewer, but the problem is the control doesn't show data. I've created a datatable and then, i created a dataset and add the datatable into a dataset to make the dataset de source of the reportviewer. Also, i've obtained an xml file just in case i can add it as source of the reportviewer (just in case that it's possible) Or are there a better solution to my problem?

```
public DataTable ListarMenuDataTable()
        {
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["App"].ToString()))
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT NombreNodo, IdentificadorNodo, IdentificadorPadre,Formulario FROM Menu", cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }

private void rbClientes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = this.oClienteDAO.ListarMenuDataTable();
            dt.TableName = "dtMenu";

            DataSet dsMenu = new DataSet();
            dsMenu.Tables.Add(dt);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Recursos\\Reportes\\Xml_" + rbClientes.Text + ".xml") == false)

            {
                dsMenu.WriteXml(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Recursos\\Reportes\\Xml_" + rbClientes.Text + ".xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            }

            this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Recursos\\Reportes\\Rpt_" + rbClientes.Text + ".rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("dtMenu",dsMenu.Tables[0]);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Comment: Im expecting that the reportviewer shows data, actually happen that it doesn't show anything, besides, the datatable is popullated by a function as its shows in the following code.